# Calculate speed given linear twist message

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a twist message and want to know what the speed of my robot.

Would it just be sqrt(twist.linear.x^2 + twist.linear.y^2)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359103/calculate-speed-given-linear-twist-message/) by [farofaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/57563/farofaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes! (for a 2D system).

---

Originally posted by [praskot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29965/praskot/) with karma: 257 on 2020-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akr2712](https://answers.ros.org/users/56740/akr2712/) on 2021-04-11**:
Is the equation similar for 3D systems (sqrt(twist.linear.x^2 + twist.linear.y^2+twist.z^2))?